# Misaligned 2 row 2 column li tag cotents

Tags: html, css

I have page section that has 2 columns and 2 rows of text.

column 1 and column contents of row 1 should always be aligned in the same line.The problem I am facing is that they are not. Column 2 is being aligned a line or 2 below column 1. This isthe behavior in  fiddle, but in my server its the other way around. This happens the media query for smaller screen kciks in.

Is there a way I can fix this?

HTML Code:

```
<section class="carousel freedom container"> <!--Freedom section -->

<ul class="two-col left-col">
 <li class="pen"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>Work</em> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT</span> </li>
<li class="arrow"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>Access </em> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT</span> </li>
</ul>
<ul class="two-col right-col">
<li class="phone"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>Go </em> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT</span> </li>
<li class="download"> <span class="icon-text"> <em>Stay </em> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</li>
</ul>
</section>   <!--End of Freedom carousel -->
```

Fiddle with css: http://jsfiddle.net/LaL6c4cx/

Comment: use `vertical-align: top;` to `.right-col` - http://jsfiddle.net/LaL6c4cx/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `vertical-align: top;` to your `.left-col, .right-col` class.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LaL6c4cx/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.left-col, .right-col {
    list-style: none;
    width: 47%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Add vertical on the class for UL:

```
.left-col, .right-col {
    list-style: none;
    width: 47%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaL6c4cx/3/)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table`:

```
.container 
{
    max-width:1050px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    display: table;/*Add display table*/
}

.left-col, .right-col {
    list-style: none;
    width: 47%;
    display: table-row;/*Add display table row*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.two-col li {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: table-cell;/*Add display table cell*/
    padding-bottom: 30px;/*Add for the space between rows*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LaL6c4cx/5/)